# Multiform checkbox works only when I Click prevous

Tags: html, jquery, validation, checkbox

I have a multi-step form, when I do validations, for example the checkbox validation that checks if the ***none of above*** option has been checked, then other options or checkboxes have to be unchecked. 
that functionality  only work when I click the previous button

```
event.preventDefault();

if($('input[name^="q3"]:checked').length ==0) {
$("#q3Error").html("Please select an option. If above choices do not meet your situation, click NONE OF THE ABOVE");
return false;

}else if($('input[name^="q3"]:checked').length >0){

 $(".noneAbove_q3").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);   
 });

  $(".check_option_3").click(function () {
     $(".noneAbove_q3").prop('checked', false);   
 });

 $("#q3Error").html("");

$("#third").hide();
$("#second").hide();

$("#fourth").show();
$("#progressBar").css("width","40%");
$("#progressText").html("Step 4");

}

});
```

it only works after I click on **previous** from the next question.

Comment: You are setting up the `click` handlers inside the `else` block, they aren't in place until step 4. Move them outside other handlers or conditionals.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank you @msg